# Selenium Webdriver: connect hub with hub

Tags: networking, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently setting up a Selenium Grid. I have a PC-A that runs several virtual machines that can only communicate with PC-A so it has to run as a hub, my main hub is running at PC-B, is it possible to register my hub on PC-A to the hub at PC-B? This way I'll be able to run the browsers on my virtual machines.
Or am I thinking in the wrong direction? The reason to run the virtual machines not on the pc where my hub is running is purely based on the performance of my PC-A.

Comment: Hi, your PC-A is using Windows or Linux? You are using Virtualbox or KVM to run the VM? Are you using "host-only" networking in VirtualBox?

Comment: I am using VMWare player, both machines run on Windows.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the [available networking modes](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_common_ws.html) in VMware player are similar to those in VMware workstation. Any reason why you don't want to use `NAT` or `Bridged mode` which will allow your VM to connect directly to PC-B? Is it due to security reason?

Comment: Thats exectly what I needed, I set it to Bridged mode and I can now connect :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to connect a hub to a hub.  That, to me, would be extremely redundant.

I think what you need to do, is run your hub at PC-B, then have the virtuals connect to that, and PC-A run as a node connecting to the main hub at PC-B since they have connection.  Your Virtuals should DEFINITELY run as nodes though.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is that the virtuals can only connect to PC-A by the nodes. For now I'll run the virtuals on PC-B, so they can connect to the main hub and run PC-A as a node as is.